# Cannot remove eventhandler in angular js $onDestroy

Tags: angularjs, eventhandler

I do this in ctor of my angular js controller:

```
   const srollHandler = (e) => {
                console.log("scrolling");
            };

            document.getElementById('auditTrailGridContainer').addEventListener("scroll", srollHandler, true);
```

This works just fine but do I have to remove `scrollHandler` manually?
I tried but this gives me an exception:

```
  this.$scope.$on("$destroy", () => {
                    console.log("destroy");
                    document.getElementById('auditTrailGridContainer').removeEventListener("scroll", srollHandler, true);
                });
```

Obviously the DOM node already has been deleted when `$destroy` kicks in.
Can I assume that angular js cleans up for me here?
If not - how would I register my eventhandler in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

You can store the reference to the element in a variable and use it later. Something like this.

```js
const srollHandler = (e) => {
    console.log("scrolling");
};

const element = document.getElementById('auditTrailGridContainer');

element.addEventListener("scroll", srollHandler, true);

// [...]

this.$scope.$on("$destroy", () => {
    console.log("destroy");
    element.removeEventListener("scroll", srollHandler, true);
});
```

Comment: okay thanks but is this even necessary? and how does this work when the dom has already been cleaned up?